# how to get text which is in frame..my code is here

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public String getTextOfFreeResponceField() throws InterruptedException{
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("textarea")));

              String Savetext=driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea")).getText();

               System.out.println("Msg= "+Savetext+"selected");

              return Savetext;
                }
```

by the above code i am unable to print the text in console...

Comment: Could you paste the HTML tag

Comment: [http://pubdev1.edcite-dev.com/apps/AssignmentViewer?exid=pankaj_1412654685736&assignid=pankaj_1412654685736]

Comment: I could not find element with "textarea" in the application link which you have posted above

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i assume that you are trying to get text from any text area and not the static text on the page. If this is the case, then you cannot use getText()

As per : [Unable to read text from textbox using gettext() of selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258207/unable-to-read-text-from-textbox-using-gettext-of-selenium-webdriver)

Refer to http://seleniumtwo-by-arun.blogspot.in/2013/06/37-using-getattributevalue-method-for.html for information on how to use getAttribute().