# Python Selenium: How to get text generated by JavaScript in input field

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a problem in getting text from user name field in one of the forms on my webpage using Python & Selenium.

I have a field that is populated by JS after selecting a User from a list:

```
<select id="users" onchange="checkUser(document.getElementById('configpin'))" ondblclick="document.getElementById('users').size=1; showUser(document.getElementById('configpin'))" onmouseout="document.getElementById('users').size=1" size="1"><option value="1">1 User 1</option>[...]</option></select>
```

The field:

```
<input name="name1" value="" type="text" id="name1" onkeyup="checkNameEntry('name1',20)" onchange="checkNameEntry('name1',20)" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) submitUser(document.getElementById('configpin'));">
```

And I am trying to get the text displayed in that field, but it does not work.
I was trying:

```
uname = driver.find_element_by_id('name1').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

AND:

```
uname = driver.find_element_by_id('name1').text
```

but in both cases, all I get from it is an empty string. I expect this is a common problem and should have some obvious solution, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analysed the web page source code a bit deeper, and it turned out, that JS actually called Ajax, and as I read in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258207/unable-to-read-text-from-textbox-using-gettext-of-selenium-webdriver), you just use .get_attribute('value') to get the text. That seemed to me odd at first, because there is no attribute 'value' in html code, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to find the element by name, like this:

```
uname = driver.find_element_by_name('name1').text
```

Check out here the official [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html).

Comment: The element is located properly, because I use this code to clear this field and input my own string in other test and it works. So it's about the Java Script I think. Either way, I tried by name locator, and the result is the same.